# Storing Versions In MySQL Using A Linked List

Tags: mysql, linked-list

I am storing versioned text in MySQL, each version is a row, and think it makes the most sense to represent the data as a linked list, since I need to say `.next` and `.prev`. What is the best way to represent this in MySQL? I am thinking just a single table:

**Table (Versions)**

```
id (PK)
next (id of the next version, if head null)
prev (id of the previous version, if last null)
data
```

Or, does it make more sense to try and normalize this, using multiple tables?

Comment: The answer could be different according to what you have to do with that list. If you want to take a whole chain related to a record, you should travel the whole list to build the chain...

Comment: Just need to do `prev` and `next`. Like a book, flip a page forward and back.

Comment: So with a single query you can take prev and next and you're ready to show desired page. Your design sounds good to me!

Comment: How does an update in the middle work? User goes and edits a version that has a prev and next?